# account_invoice_entry_date on odoo 10

Tags: python, odoo-10

The module account_invoice_entry_date is marked as deprecated in the [OCA  GitHub repository](https://github.com/OCA/l10n-italy/issues/254)
Does anyone know if there is some alternative to this module, maybe built in Odoo 10?

Answer (score 0):

Answered own question: still not ported from version 8 to 10. Someone is working on it.

Answer (score 0):

In odoo core, you can find the `Accounting Date` field in `other info` tab of supplier invoices.

Ref. https://github.com/OCA/l10n-italy/issues/254#issuecomment-345619476